# Custom Images with GAN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I downloaded this image set https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/stanford-dogs-dataset

and extracted those images folder in to my data folder

So now it's like this
[image]

Below is my code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.utils.data
import torchvision.datasets as dset
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.utils as vutils
from torch.autograd import Variable
import os

batchSize = 64  # We set the size of the batch.
imageSize = 64  # We set the size of the generated images (64x64).

# Creating the transformations
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Scale(imageSize), transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5,
                                                                       0.5)), ])  # We create a list of transformations (scaling, tensor conversion, normalization) to apply to the input images.

# Loading the dataset
dataset = dset.ImageFolder(root='./data', transform=transform)
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batchSize, shuffle=True,
                                         num_workers=2)  # We use dataLoader to get the images of the training set batch by batch.


# Defining the weights_init function that takes as input a neural network m and that will initialize all its weights.
def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        m.weight.data.normal_(0.0, 0.02)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm') != -1:
        m.weight.data.normal_(1.0, 0.02)
        m.bias.data.fill_(0)


input_vector = 100


# Create results directory
def create_dir(name):
    if not os.path.exists(name):
        os.makedirs(name)


# Defining the Generator
class G(nn.Module):
    feature_maps = 512
    kernel_size = 4
    stride = 2
    padding = 1
    bias = False

    def __init__(self):
        super(G, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(input_vector, self.feature_maps, self.kernel_size, 1, 0, bias=self.bias),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(self.feature_maps), nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(self.feature_maps, int(self.feature_maps // 2), self.kernel_size, self.stride, self.padding,
                               bias=self.bias),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(int(self.feature_maps // 2)), nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(int(self.feature_maps // 2), int((self.feature_maps // 2) // 2), self.kernel_size, self.stride,
                               self.padding,
                               bias=self.bias),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(int((self.feature_maps // 2) // 2)), nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d((int((self.feature_maps // 2) // 2)), int(((self.feature_maps // 2) // 2) // 2), self.kernel_size,
                               self.stride, self.padding,
                               bias=self.bias),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(int((self.feature_maps // 2) // 2) // 2), nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(int(((self.feature_maps // 2) // 2) // 2), 3, self.kernel_size, self.stride, self.padding,
                               bias=self.bias),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        output = self.main(input)
        return output


# Creating the generator
netG = G()
netG.apply(weights_init)


class D(nn.Module):
    feature_maps = 64
    kernel_size = 4
    stride = 2
    padding = 1
    bias = False
    inplace = True

    def __init__(self):
        super(D, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, self.feature_maps, self.kernel_size, self.stride, self.padding, bias=self.bias),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=self.inplace),
            nn.Conv2d(self.feature_maps, self.feature_maps * 2, self.kernel_size, self.stride, self.padding,
                      bias=self.bias),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(self.feature_maps * 2), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=self.inplace),
            nn.Conv2d(self.feature_maps * 2, self.feature_maps * (2 * 2), self.kernel_size, self.stride, self.padding,
                      bias=self.bias),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(self.feature_maps * (2 * 2)), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=self.inplace),
            nn.Conv2d(self.feature_maps * (2 * 2), self.feature_maps * (2 * 2 * 2), self.kernel_size, self.stride,
                      self.padding, bias=self.bias),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(self.feature_maps * (2 * 2 * 2)), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=self.inplace),
            nn.Conv2d(self.feature_maps * (2 * 2 * 2), 1, self.kernel_size, 1, 0, bias=self.bias),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        output = self.main(input)
        return output.view(-1)


# Creating the discriminator
netD = D()
netD.apply(weights_init)

# Training the DCGANs
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizerD = optim.Adam(netD.parameters(), lr=0.002, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
optimizerG = optim.Adam(netG.parameters(), lr=0.002, betas=(0.5, 0.999))

nb_epochs = 25

for epoch in range(25):

    for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):

        # 1st Step: Updating the weights of the neural network of the discriminator

        netD.zero_grad()

        # Training the discriminator with a real image of the dataset
        real, _ = data
        input = Variable(real)
        target = Variable(torch.ones(input.size()[0]))
        output = netD(input)
        errD_real = criterion(output, target)

        # Training the discriminator with a fake image generated by the generator
        noise = Variable(torch.randn(input.size()[0], 100, 1, 1))
        fake = netG(noise)
        target = Variable(torch.zeros(input.size()[0]))
        output = netD(fake.detach())
        errD_fake = criterion(output, target)

        # Backpropagating the total error
        errD = errD_real + errD_fake
        errD.backward()
        optimizerD.step()

        # 2nd Step: Updating the weights of the neural network of the generator

        netG.zero_grad()
        target = Variable(torch.ones(input.size()[0]))
        output = netD(fake)
        errG = criterion(output, target)
        errG.backward()
        optimizerG.step()

        # 3rd Step: Printing the losses and saving the real images and the generated images of the minibatch every 100 steps

        print('[%d/%d][%d/%d] Loss_D: %.4f Loss_G: %.4f' % (epoch, 25, i, len(dataloader), errD.data[0], errG.data[0]))
        if i % 100 == 0:
            vutils.save_image(real, '%s/real_samples.png' % "./results", normalize=True)
            fake = netG(noise)
            vutils.save_image(fake.data, '%s/fake_samples_epoch_%03d.png' % ("./results", epoch), normalize=True)
```

But when I run that it gives me this error

```
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 64, 85] at entry 0 and [3, 64, 80] at entry 1
```

That means the issue is with the for loop.
How can I change that for loop to match my dataset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [transforms.Resize](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Resize) instead of `transforms.Scale(imageSize)`, as Resize behaves differently on input images with a different height and width. Pass the size argument as a tuple:

```
....
transforms.Resize((imageSize, imageSize))
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error means that it's trying to stack the images into batches, but the images are different sizes, i.e. the first image is size 3 x 64 x 85 and the second image is 3 x 64 x 80. You'll probably need to transform (resize) the images so that they're all the same shape.